# Regex - find all comments with specific string

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

Can someone help me with this Javascript regex (it will be running in Gulp)? I want something that will find all one-line comments (both Java and HTML) that have the text "CommentText." These are the two formats:

```
/* CommentText */
<!-- Comment Text -->
```

Here is the regex I'm trying, but it's only finding the first one (the Java comment):

```
(\/*|\/<!--)(.|(CommentText)|[\r\n])*?(\*\/|\/-->)
```

Comment: Please specify which regex tool you are using. They are all different. For example, `/` is not a special character and does not need to be escaped, unless you are working in Python or JavaScript.

Comment: This will run in Gulp, so I need Javascript. Updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex would work:

```
(\/\*|<!--)\s?(Comment\s?Text)\s?(\*\/|-->)
```

With the comment's text located in the third capture group: `(.*)`

[Example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DWzpMG/5)

Comment: You forget the `Comment\s?Text` part too

Comment: You're right, thanks! I misread the question & thought it was an example.

Comment: I get this error when trying to run this expression:

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/*|<!--)s?(Comments?Text)s?(*/|-->)/: Nothing to repeat